# Python + ZeroMQ - proper handling of finite stream of data in PUSH/PULL model

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm trying to implement a distributed PUSH/PULL (some kinda MapReduce) model with Python and ZMQ, as it's described here: http://taotetek.net/2011/02/02/python-multiprocessing-with-zeromq/ . In this example, **result_manager** knows exactly how many messages to wait and when to send "FINISHED" state to workers.

Let's assume I have a big but finite stream of data of unknown length. In this case I can't know exactly where to stop. I tried to send "FINISHED" from **ventilator** in the end instead of **result_manager**, but, of course, workers receive it in the middle of processing (due to the fact that it's a separate channel) and die immediately, so a lot of data is lost.

Otherwise, if I use the same **work_message** queue to send "FINISHED" state - it's being captured by first available worker while others hang, that's also as expected.

Is there any other model I should use here? Or can you please point me to some best practices for this case?

Comment: I also thought about making each worker put back the "FINISHED" message to be captured by others in second case, but this seems like an awful dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

> Otherwise, if I use the same work_message queue to send "FINISHED"
>   state - it's being captured by first available worker while others
>   hang, that's also as expected.

You can easily work around this.

1. Send `"FINISH"` from **VENTILATOR** to **RESULT_MANAGER** `PULL socket`.
2. **RESULT_MANAGER** receives `"FINISH"` and publishes this message to all **WORKERS** through `PUB socket`.
3. All **WORKERS** receive `"FINISH"` message on `SUB sockets` and kill themselves.

Here you have example code from the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Divide-and-Conquer) how to send sth from **VENTILATOR** to **RESULT_MANAGER** in devide and conquer design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. The thing is, in this approach workers still receive FINISHED signal asynchronously and they are killed when data's still left in buffer. Currently I solved it like this: I created another channel between ventilator and result_manager, and both of them are also counting lines which are passing through. After the input is finished, ventilator sends total number of lines to be processed to result_manager, and on each new output data chunk received it compares its own counter with the total number of records to be processed. In case they're equal - that's the end.

Comment: That's understandable. My point is that you had problem with distributing "FINISH" from VENTILATOR and I gave you an idea only how to reuse existing connections to distribute "FINISH" message from VENTILATOR to every WORKER. I didn't respond to synchronization problem because I had to little information about data/stream which you are distributing.